# Formula Field to filter contacts to synchronize in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, formula-field, marketing-cloud-connect

We would like to use a formula boolean field to synchronize contacts from Salesforce CRM to SFMC.

We know that formula fields are specific and that we should care about its use, because alone it doesn't allow itself any trigger.

Cf.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_implement_synchronized_data_sources_best_practices.htm&type=5

> **Understand How Formula Fields Update with Synchronized Data Sources**
>
> Formula fields contained in Synchronized Data Sources update only
> when an update for another field on the object occurs. Formula fields
> do not trigger a change to an object or update last modified date
> fields. When an update occurs, all synchronized formula fields for
> that object evaluate and update as necessary. Use performant SOQL in
> those synchronized formula fields to avoid slow synchronization, as
> these evaluations take place for every field update.

**My question:**

We would like to use a formula field on CONTACT to synchronize contacts from CRM to SFMC.

ALL the fields used in the formula are also on CONTACT (and PersonAccount).
So when at least one of the Contact field contained in the formula is modified, and that it updates the formula field, as there is a modification on the record, that should trigger the synchronization.
Could you please confirm that in that specific case, we can use this formula field as the field that will filter the Contacts from CRM to synchronize with SFMC ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct and also something I have done myself in few implementations. As you define your formula to only contain fields from your contact record, the formula will also update when the referenced fields are updated.

An example is this formula here, which was used to only allow contacts/leads who’ve had historical activities in Pardot:

```
NOT(ISBLANK(pi__last_activity__c))
```

The issue of having a formula reference fields on other objects is the fact, that an update there will not trigger the update of the contact record, hence the formula field will not update either.

Comment: Thanks a lot! that helps and avoid creating a new field with process builder/workflows, etc.